# Effect of bandwidth of stator winding in induction motor

Tags: motor, motor-controller, induction-motor

The stator in squirrel cage induction motors is an RL circuit with 3db attenuation
$$
\frac{R}{2\pi L}Hz
$$

Does that mean an IM designed for 60Hz should also have the stator bandwidth at least 60Hz? My argument is that if the stator winding bandwidth was only 0.1Hz (for an extreme example), then a 60Hz signal would be too quick for the circuit and the circuit cannot respond to the input. Also, the current would be too low to produce any torque in the machine at 60Hz.

I have an IM and estimated the 3db bandwidth to be only 20Hz. I wanted to run it at 60Hz using a low cost VFD.

Comment: Does your induction motor have a nameplate? The vast, vast majority are designed for 50/60Hz or 100Hz+, except for a few for 16.7Hz railways, which I would expect to all be single-phase.

Comment: The frequency in the rotor (slip) is usually fairly low (3-5Hz) - it only sees line frequency during starting.

Comment: Actually an old motor was repaired with DIY methods (old/damaged windings were replaced and rotor was cleaned a bit). The name plate data is missing and is also probably invalid because of the repair. But since I have this motor, I wanted to know the limitations on its operating frequency.